# How to save multiple records at once into a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, database, activerecord

I have a forEach that loops through a number of objects and then creates a record in the database for each item.

```
angular.forEach($scope.movieCredits.credits.cast, function(item){
  createActor.create({
    name:       item.name,
    character:  item.character,
    movie_id:   movieRecordID[0].id,
  })
})
```

While this does work, it's quite slow (some movies have 50+ cast members, that's a lot of posts requests to the database). Is there a better way to save multiple objects into the database?

This is the create function in my actor controller,

```
def create
  Actor.find_or_create_by(movie_id: params[:movie_id], name: params[:name], character: params[:character])
  redirect_to :root
end
```

*** update ***

Log from my rails console,

```
Started POST "/actors.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-12 16:15:35 +0100
Processing by ActorsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"_json"=>[{"name"=>"John Travolta", "character"=>"Vincent Vega", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Samuel L. Jackson", "character"=>"Jules Winfield", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Uma Thurman", "character"=>"Mia Wallace", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Bruce Willis", "character"=>"Butch Coolidge", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Ving Rhames", "character"=>"Marsellus Wallace", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Harvey Keitel", "character"=>"Wolf", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Eric Stoltz", "character"=>"Lance", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Tim Roth", "character"=>"Pumpkin", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Amanda Plummer", "character"=>"Honey Bunny", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Maria de Medeiros", "character"=>"Fabienne", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Quentin Tarantino", "character"=>"Jimmie Dimmick", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Christopher Walken", "character"=>"Captain Koons", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Rosanna Arquette", "character"=>"Jody", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Peter Greene", "character"=>"Zed", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Duane Whitaker", "character"=>"Maynard", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Angela Jones", "character"=>"Esmarelda Villalobos", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Phil LaMarr", "character"=>"Marvin", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Steve Buscemi", "character"=>"Buddy Holly", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Bronagh Gallagher", "character"=>"Trudi", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Laura Lovelace", "character"=>"Waitress", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Frank Whaley", "character"=>"Brett", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Burr Steers", "character"=>"Roger", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Paul Calderon", "character"=>"Paul", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Jerome Patrick Hoban", "character"=>"Ed Sullivan", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Michael Gilden", "character"=>"Page for Phillip Morris", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Gary Shorelle", "character"=>"Ricky Nelson", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Susan Griffiths", "character"=>"Marilyn Monroe", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Eric Clark", "character"=>"James Dean", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Joseph Pilato", "character"=>"Dean Martin", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Brad Blumenthal", "character"=>"Jerry Lewis (as Brad Parker)", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Lorelei Leslie", "character"=>"Mamie van Doren", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Emil Sitka", "character"=>"Hold Hands You Lovebirds (archive footage)", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Brenda Hillhouse", "character"=>"Mrs. Coolidge - Butch's Mother", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Chandler Lindauer", "character"=>"Young Butch", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Sy Sher", "character"=>"Klondike", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Robert Ruth", "character"=>"Sportscaster #1 - Coffee Shop", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Rich Turner", "character"=>"Sportscaster #2", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Don Blakely", "character"=>"Wilson's Trainer", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Carl Allen", "character"=>"Dead Floyd Wilson", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Karen Maruyama", "character"=>"Gawker #1", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Kathy Griffin", "character"=>"Hit-and-run Witness", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Venessia Valentino", "character"=>"Pedestrian / Bonnie Dimmick", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Linda Kaye", "character"=>"Shot Woman", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Stephen Hibbert", "character"=>"The Gimp", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Alexis Arquette", "character"=>"Man No. 4", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Julia Sweeney", "character"=>"Raquel", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Lawrence Bender", "character"=>"Long Hair Yuppy Scum", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Cie Allman", "character"=>"Winston Wolfe's Girlfriend At Party (uncredited)", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Rene Beard", "character"=>"Bar Tender (uncredited)", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Lori Pizzo", "character"=>"Lucky Lady (uncredited)", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Glendon Rich", "character"=>"Drug Dealer (uncredited)", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Devan Richardson", "character"=>"Hopalong Cassidy (uncredited)", "movie_id"=>680}, {"name"=>"Ani Sava", "character"=>"Woman in Bathroom (uncredited)", "movie_id"=>680}], "actor"=>{}}
  User Load (2.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "actors" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2016-01-12 15:15:35.503383"], ["updated_at", "2016-01-12 15:15:35.503383"]]
   (11.9ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 31ms (ActiveRecord: 15.0ms)
```

Comment: why aren't you making a loop that will build the data and each 20 or 30 cast member send 1 big insert query?

Comment: @Gal would that result in 1 record being created? So the name and character value of each actor would be stored in one record? Instead of multiple records as is the result now?

Comment: SQL Server Example `INSERT INTO Table ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES
( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )` This would insert multiple records

Comment: @Malkus what can i do with that?

Comment: I would recommend using an ORM of sorts at the backend. All you would need to do then (with most ORMs) is provide an multidimensional array (correctly mapped of course) to the insert method and you're off... But you would still need to hash the data (hash as in array)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have tagged the question with Ruby on Rails so I assumed you are using ActiveRecord. So,build an api for batch inserting as follows.

You angular code should look like the following

```
var actors = [];
angular.forEach($scope.movieCredits.credits.cast, function(item){
  actors.push({
    name:       item.name,
    character:  item.character,
    movie_id:   movieRecordID[0].id,
  });
});
createActor.create(actors);
```

And in your rails controller

```
def create
  actors = Actor.create(params[:actors])
  ..
  render json: actors
end
```

This is how active records handles inserting multiple records since the `create` methods takes an array too as follows

```
Model.create([{name: "John Doe", character: "The Hobbit", movie_id: 1}, {name: "Christian Bale", character: "Batman", movie_id: 2}])
```

This will execute ONE SQL query for N records instead of N SQL queries for N records.

Comment: So you fill the empty actor array by .push, which pushes each item into the  actor array right? Then use that array to post using the `createActor` service? I've tried it, and in my rails log I see all the actors etc. but my actor table remains empty. I think it's because of the create funcion in my rails controller. I've added it to my question, maybe you can see if my hunge is correct? Thank you for the insight anyway.

Comment: `find_or_create_by` finds or creates a single record and can not take an array. You have to use the `create` method and handle duplicates with validations.

Comment: Okay but how do I add the parameters to the `create` method? I've got this now, `actors = Actor.create(actor_params)` and `private def actor_params params.permit( :name, :character, :movie_id) end` there are new records created but it's empty.

Comment: You do not permit `:name, :character, :movie_id` anymore since now your params are an array. Can you comment with the params sent to your backend?

Comment: Alright, so how does rails know what values should be inserted? I've added the result of doing the create action in the question.

Comment: You need to `Actor.create(params["_json"])`